# Dynamic Hostnames from DHCP in Autoinstall

Tags: subiquity

In the user_data autoinstall I have being served via tftp, the hostname field is required.  I'm using statically mapped dhcp entries to match machine to hostname, ip, etc.

How can I get the autoinstall hostname to accept the value from dhcp on pxe boot?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any way to make *subiquity* use the hostname in the DHCP offer.  However, there are a number of ways that `early-commands` and `late-commands` could be used to do what you want.

My suggested solution is a `user-data` autoinstall file similar to this snippet.  It will read the hostname in the DHCP offer from the DHCP lease file and overwrite `/etc/hostname` on the installed system.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  # NO identity section
  #identity:
  user-data:
    users:
    - name: ubuntu
      passwd: REDACTED
      shell: /bin/bash
      lock-passwd: false
      sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
      groups: users
  late-commands:
    - |
      bash <<'EOF'
        source <(cat /run/systemd/netif/leases/* | grep ^HOSTNAME=)
        [[ -n "${HOSTNAME}" ]] && echo "${HOSTNAME}" > /target/etc/hostname
      EOF
      true
```

These are some gotchas to watch out for no matter what approach you try.

- The `autoinstall` `identity` and `user-data` sections do not co-exist well.  My preference is to use a `user-data` section and to not include an `identity` section.  Because the only provided way to configure the hostname is the `identity` section another method must be used to configure the hostname (e.g. `late-commands`).
- If there is no `identity` section then *subiquity* changes behavior.  The generated *cloud-init* configuration (in `/target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg`) will be different.  There will be no `/target/etc/hosts` content generated and the file will be left empty.  There are potentially other differences.
- Conversely, if there is an `identity` section then the provided `hostname` will be configured in multiple files.  In `/target/etc/hosts` and potentially others.

**see also**

- [Cloud-config-auto install (late comands random hostname + netwrok config)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1419162/cloud-config-auto-install-late-comands-random-hostname-netwrok-config/1419373#1419373)
- [How can I run complex piped commands in Autoinstall / Cloud-Init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390768/how-can-i-run-complex-piped-commands-in-autoinstall-cloud-init/1392251#1392251)
- [Ubuntu Server 20.04 cloud-config adding user does nothing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385066/ubuntu-server-20-04-cloud-config-adding-user-does-nothing/1385096#1385096)

**notes**

- I tested using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).