Autoinstall, landscape and generated `computer_title`
Is there a way to automatically generate the value for the option computer_title while running the setup?
I thought about using Jinja2, but I don't find a documentation how to change computer_title on the fly in the setup.
How the configuration currently looks:
user-data:  
landscape:  
  client:  
    log_level: "info"  
    account_name: "MyAccount"  
    computer_title: "SomeName"  

What I want to achieve:
user-data:  
landscape:  
  client:  
    log_level: "info"  
    account_name: "MyAccount"  
    computer_title: "{{ /usr/bin/bash echo "$(date +%s)-$RANDOM" }}" 

Any ideas how to solve this?

You can try the early-commands solution from https://askubuntu.com/a/1419373/376778

Thanks, I will try it
